# Where to define SSL connection with Hibernate reactive

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, mutiny, hibernate-reactive

I'm running spring webflux app with Hibernate reactive defined like wise:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME, hibernateReactiveProperties());
Mutiny.SessionFactory reactiveSessionFactory = emf.unwrap(Mutiny.SessionFactory.class);
```

Version:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.reactive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-reactive-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
 </dependency>
```

I'm using Postgresql, `javax.persistence.jdbc.driver : io.vertx.pgclient.spi.PgDriver12`
How do I configure an SSL connection?

Comment: Have you tried something like this in the YML `javax:
  persistence:
    jdbc:
      url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema-name?enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2
      user: username
      password: password`